# ERROR: function ident_current(unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to returns the last identity value set on a specified table in any scope of any
process using function. But getting an error:

```
ERROR:  function ident_current(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ident_current('testing')
```

**Example**:

```
/* Function */

create or replace function test(s int,n text,g text,a text, out sn int) as
$$
Begin
insert into testing(ssn,name,gender,address) values(s,n,g,a);

     sn := ident_current('testing');

select sn;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

**Function Calling**:

```
Select test(1,'a','b','c');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ident_current() doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, see the error message, but you could use [currval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html). An easier solution would be RETURNING:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(IN s INT, IN n TEXT, IN g TEXT, IN a TEXT, OUT sn INT) AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO testing(ssn,name,gender,address) VALUES(s,n,g,a)
  RETURNING id INTO sn; -- I used the name id, don't know your col

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```